# Revision history missing on closed and re-opened questions?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, information-display, revisions-list

I believe that the question [What are some famous one-liner or two-liner programs and algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4114009/2509)  on Stack Overflow was closed and has been reopened.

But no "edit history" link is available.

Change in policy, bug, something else?

Comment: As a side note, [this userscript](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts/raw/master/SEModifications.user.js) will put a history link on every question/answer for this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the "edited" link only shows up if the post has been edited, even though it records and closes/re-openings. You can still see the [revisions list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4114009/revisions).

The close and re-open also show up in [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4114009/timeline).